# Excel COUNTIFS referencing two different columns

Tags: excel, countif

Trying to create a countifs statement which counts the number of "N" in one column, but only if those "N" occur on a certain week number (the date is listed in another column).

I have tried =COUNTIFS('Team 3-4-5'!$O$6:$O$46,"=N",'Team 3-4-5'!$N$6:$N$46,(WEEKNUM('Team 3-4-5'!$N$6:$N$46)=WEEKNUM(Sheet1!B1))) but it does not seem to work.

The formula does not give me an error, but does not give me the answer i am looking for.

Help!

Comment: I deleted my answer as it was incorrect.  See [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28566794/sumifs-with-date-criteria-month-and-year-only/28567292#285672920) as is basically the same problem

Comment: Thank you chancea. However, if the intent was to "count" the number of "N" in a column, how does sumifs deal with a non-number value? I tried my hand at a "SUMIFS" version of my formula:                   =SUMIFS('Team 3-4-5'!$P$6:$P$46,'Team 3-4-5'!$M$6:$M$46,"="&Sheet1!B7,'Team 3-4-5'!$P$6:$P$46,"N")                   But I am still not having any luck.

Comment: Figured it out. The reason i was having issues was because i was entering the "Criteria" as an equation, instead of entering a value or cell reference i wanted to compare the range to. Once i figured that out, formula works exactly as planned!