# SUMIFS with date and name criteria... month and year only

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, sumifs

I am trying to get a SUMIFS formula to check a column of dates and sum only the values that correspond to the matching year and month of the criterion date. I would also like this SUMIFS to include a name criterion along with the date. i.e.

Cell A1: `=SUMIFS('Sheet1'!O:O, 'Sheet1'!D:D, 'Sheet2'!DATE(B2), 'Sheet1'!E:E, "Name")`

sheet1 column O is where the sum values are stored
sheet1 column D is where the date values are stored
sheet2 cell B2 is where the date comparison criterion is stored
sheet1 column E is where the names are stored
"Name" is the name criterion that I want for sum selection

Any insight will be most appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You **can** use `SUMIFS` if you create a start and end date for your dates, i.e. with this version

```
=SUMIFS('Sheet1'!O:O,'Sheet1'!D:D, ">="&EOMONTH('Sheet2'!B2,-1)+1, 'Sheet1'!D:D, "<"&EOMONTH('Sheet2'!B2,0)+1, 'Sheet1'!E:E, "Name")
```

`EOMONTH` is used to get the start and end dates of the relevant month then your `SUMIFS` sums the correct values based on your other criteria.

If `B2` is guaranteed to be the first of the month you can omit the first `EOMONTH` function

Comment: Ah didn't even think of using a range of dates

Comment: Given a) the roughly 3× efficiency of `SUMIFS` over `SUMPRODUCT` b) the ability to use full column references and c) the ability to happily skip over non-conforming values that would throw `SUMPRODUCT` into conniptions this is the vastly preferred method.

Comment: @Jeeped With array formulas you can accomplish points b and c.  And not that I am disagreeing that `SUMIFS` is probably faster, but how do you know the efficiency of each formula?

Comment: @chancea - I've run speed tests of sumproduct vs sumif, sumifs, countif and countifs using the same number of identical criteria both with full column referencing in sumproduct and with sumproduct limited to the extents of the data (with the others remaining at full column referencing). Sumproduct at best takes 3× as long to complete a calculation cycle.

Comment: @Jeeped - thanks for the edit and useful comments - appreciated

Answer (score 0):

**Solution with SUMPRODUCT**

I find it simpler to use `SUMPRODUCT` in situations like this.

For no header row you can simple use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(Sheet1!D:D)=MONTH(Sheet2!$B$2))*(YEAR(Sheet1!D:D)=YEAR(Sheet2!$B$2))*(Sheet1!E:E="Name"),Sheet1!O:O)
```

Just replace `"Name"` with what you want.

If you have a header row (or if the column contains any values that are not valid dates) you need to use an array formula within `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((IF(ISERROR(MONTH(Sheet1!D:D)),Sheet1!D:D,MONTH(Sheet1!D:D))=MONTH(Sheet2!$B$2))*(IF(ISERROR(YEAR(Sheet1!D:D)),Sheet1!D:D,YEAR(Sheet1!D:D))=YEAR(Sheet2!$B$2))*(Sheet1!E:E="Name"),Sheet1!O:O)
```

*(Array formulas are entered using `ctrl` + `shft` + `enter`)*

Comment: Ok, still no luck. Here is the new code I used as you suggested (Ive since renamed sheets and moved a few columns around. '=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(SupportCalls!F:F)=MONTH(Calculations!B3))*(YEAR(SupportCalls!F:F)=YEAR(Calculations!B3))*(SupportCalls!E:E=K9),SupportCalls!P:P)'

Comment: the error says that a "value in the formula is of the wrong data type"

Comment: You will get a #VALUE! error if you apply MONTH or YEAR function to a text value, so that will happen where you use the whole column and you have header values in row 1 or any other text - it's better to use the specific date range - or check out my solution using SUMIFS - generally that will be more efficient